# Call rings on bluetooth headphones, but when i pickup it defaults to the call being on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, audio, bluetooth, headphones

I have my iPhone connected to a pair of bluetooth headphones for listening to music.

If someone calls while im listening to music the call will ring on the headphones, but as soon as i pickup the call, by using "slide to answer" on the iPhone; the call starts on my phone eg. through the phone's earpiece, i then have to manually select the call to be taken through the headphones.

Is there anyway i can set the iPhone to continue the call through the headphones by default ?

Im running ios 11.3 on an iPhone 7.

The bluetooth headphones im using are Bose quiet comfort 35.

Comment: How specifically are you answering the call?  Also you didn’t tell us ‘which’ Bluetooth headset, so we can’t look up the manual for you.

Comment: I have the same issue. I actually think it's by design. When I answer by pushing the button on my headphones it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phone calls audio will be routed to the device you accept your phone call with. Use the play/pause button on your headphones to pick up, then the headset will be used for the phone call.

Comment: So it's because I answer it using my phone instead of using my headphones? Can I change this setting?

Comment: Accessibility -> Touch -> Call Audio Routing

Comment: setting Accessibility -> Touch -> Call Audio Routing to BT headset didn't help in my case